# Petición REST en javaScript

Tags: javascript, rest

Estoy intentando implementar un cliente REST en JavaScript. Parece ser que no manda la petición. Este código está dentro de un fichero html. 
Espero que me podáis ayudar.

```
function doFunction() {
    document.getElementById('oculto').style.display = 'block';

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "http://192.168.1.145:1026/v1/updateContext";

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true,"","");

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");

    var payload = '{ "contextElements" : [{ "type":"SmartBand" , "isPattern":"false", "id":"Smart3", "attributes":[{"name":"heartrate","type":"int","value":"0"}]}],"updateAction":"APPEND"}';      

    xmlhttp.send(JSON.parse(payload));
    //xmlhttp.send(payload);

    if (this.status == 200)
        alert("Va bien");
    else 
        alert("No va bien");                            
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Exactamente, qué es lo que pasa? ¿No sale ningún mensaje, sale el mensaje de "No va bien"? Si sale el mensaje de "No va bien", ¿cual es el httpStatus? En todo caso, a) nunca asignas un valor a `this.status` y b) revisa algún ejemplo porque no es así como se tratan las respuestas de peticiones asíncronas.

Answer (score 1):

La petición es asincrónica (true en el tercer parámetro del open). Eso significa que después de open el programa javascript sigue ejecutándose sin haber establecido la conexión todavía.

Hay que avisarle al objeto `xmlhttp` que avise cuando tenga novedades de la conexión. Por ejemplo así:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(event){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
            alert("Fue bien");
        else 
            alert("No fue bien "+xmlhttp.status+' '+xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(JSON.parse(payload));
```

Así en el evento `onreadystatechange` se puede monitorear el avance y finalizlación de la llamada ajax (con `readyState == 4` estoy controlando solo cuando el cambio de estado es a finalizado, pero existen otros cambios de estado).

ver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest y https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

Una aclaración: el método `open` acepta tres parámetros **por lo general**: método http, dirección url y una bandera para indicar si la petición será asíncrona o síncrona (si no entiendes que significa esto, revisar el concepto antes de proseguir), por defecto este último parámetro es `true`. **Si no usarás autenticación no tiene sentido usar los parámetros username y password** porque por defecto su valor es `null`.

Segundo, estás usando `this` dentro de una función; el uso de `this` es JavaScript difiere de lo que estás acostumbrado a ver en otros lenguajes; existen ya preguntas sobre esto en el sitio que puedes consultar, ya que la explicación tienda a ser extensa.

Cuando haces `this.status === 200` estás diciendo en realidad `window.status === 200` lo cual te dará falso porque `window.status` es `undefined`. Dentro de una función pura, por defecto `this` hace referencia al objeto global `window`.

La solución que te da @EmilioPlatzer es válida, pero es más aplicable cuando deseas hacer un *rastreo de la petición*. Una petición [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) contiene **cinco fases o estados**:

- 0: la petición aún no es inicializada.
- 1: se establece una conexión con el servidor.
- 2: se recibe la petición.
- 3: se procesa la petición.
- 4: la petición es resuelta y la respuesta devuelta.

Es en la etapa 4 en donde debes hacer tu proceso ya que en este punto el servidor ya ha retornado una respuesta. Como dije anteriormente, por medio de `onrequeststatechange` lo que se hace es escuchar por cada cambio de estado de la petición; si lo que quieres es simplemente ejecutar algo cuando obtienes la respuesta del servidor, usa el evento `load`:

```
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
  if (this.status === 200) {
    alert('va bien');
  } else {
    alert('va mal');
  }
}
```

Las diferencias son mínimas, `readystatechange` forma parte de la especificación original, mientras que `load` apareció en la especificación de XMLHttpRequest2.